# javascript scope rules for functions using this identifier

Tags: javascript, scope

I wrote following piece of code in order to explore the javascript scope rules
for functions that use the this identifier. I would expect the second invocation 
of person.helloFunk() to print the name "Marvin" and the age "very very old" since I 
created the attributes navn and age on the function object itself, but it doesn't. 
In stead it repeats the same output "Hello, I'm zaphod and I'm 42 years old".
So why is it that this refers to the object that the function is embedded in and not the function itself (which is also an object)?

```
var sayHello = function() {
    return "Hello, I'm " + this.navn + " and I'm " + this.age + " years old.";
}
var person = {navn: 'zaphod', age: 42};
person.helloFunk = sayHello;
console.log(person.helloFunk());

sayHello.navn = 'Marvin';
sayHello.age = 'verry verry old';
console.log(person.helloFunk());
console.log(person.helloFunk.navn);
console.log(person.helloFunk.age);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are setting members on the function instead of the person object.
If you set thoe person object's member, then "this" in the function will refer to the right data.
     person.navn = 'Marvin'
     console.log(person.helloFunk()); //will printout "Hello, I'm Marvin and I'm 42 years old."

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is, ["because that is the way JavaScript is supposed to work"](http://es5.github.io/#x10.4.3). `this` is dynamic and resolves relative to the container (`global|window` if there is no other container, unless in strict mode, in which case it is `undefined`).

If you want to *change* what `this` points at you can use [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call), [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply), or [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind):

```
// call and apply differ only in how you pass arguments
// In this case, no arguments, so the invocation is the same
person.helloFunk.call(sayHello);
person.helloFunk.apply(sayHello);

var boundHello = person.helloFunk.bind(sayHello);
boundHello();
```

Comment: I think passing a function (`sayHello`) as context to `call`, `apply`, and `bind` is really a bad idea, and a bad example. It's supposed to be an object that the function uses as `this`.

Comment: @Ziarno - in this case, it's had the necessary data added to it - and a function *is* an object in JavaScript after all.  `sayHello instanceof Object === true`

Answer (score 0):

`this` does not point to the function itself, but rather to an object that invokes it.

```
function sayHello() {
  return this.hello;
}

sayHello.hello = "hi!";

console.log(sayHello()); //undefined
```

When you try to run this code:

```
var sayHello = function() {
    return "Hello, I'm " + this.navn + " and I'm " + this.age + " years old.";
}

sayHello.navn = 'Marvin';
sayHello.age = 'verry verry old';

var person = {navn: 'zaphod', age: 42};
person.helloFunk = sayHello;
console.log(person.helloFunk());
```

`this` refers to `person`, not `sayHello`.